# Uncaught TypeError: String is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and as part of my project for college I need to include some. I created a simple .js file and linked it to my index.html file using `<script src="main.js"></script>`

I created another page called `sellYourHome.html` and added a `<section>` tag with a table and created a simple form that calculates a comission and displays the results back in the input field.

```
function comCalc()
{
 prcHouse = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prcHouse').value);
 commision =  0.25; 
 result = prcHouse * commision;
 document.getElementById('prcHouse').value = result.toString();
}
```

That worked.

Now under that function, I wanted to create another one that picks up a `<div>` element and changes the `background-color` to, say, blue.

So I created a form on `index.html` and linked the same .js file to it in the same way.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <p>hello</p>
    <form id="bgColor">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="blue" onclick="bgColor('blue');">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form><!-- end of bgColor Form-->
</div>
```

My javascript is like so:

```
function comCalc()
{
    prcHouse = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prcHouse').value);
    commision =  0.25;  
    result = prcHouse * commision;
    document.getElementById('prcHouse').value = result.toString();
}

function bgColor(color)
{
  var div = document.getElementById('mainContent');
  div.style.background=color;  
}
```

When I run this, I get this error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: String is not a function

I am running this in a browser called SWRIron (which is based on Chrome and is HTML5-complient).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see `sting` anywhere

Comment: My appolgies Typo sting in both instances = "String"

Answer (score 5):

It's because of your function name `bgColor`, because `bgcolor` is an attribute of `HTML` element and it's clashing with your function `bgcolor`, browser treats this as an `attribute` (string) but you used it as a function, so it says `string is not a function`. So, change the function name to anything else like this

```
function setBgColor(color)
{
    var div = document.getElementById('mainContent');
    div.style.background = color;
}
```

Use it as

```
<input type="button" value="blue" onclick="setBgColor('blue');" />
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xH9vg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since bgColor is system reserved for HMTL, it throws an error called "Uncaught TypeError: String is not a function". if you change the method name, it will work fine and works fine.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the other answer.